# How to Invoke a JavaScript in a vb.net automation script

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a automation script that performs a click on an element on a web page using vb.net. I created something like this in java using selenium to find the element and then click:

```
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divMenu20100608192545780709']/div[3]"));
    String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, test);
    if( test.isDisplayed()){
        jscript.executeScript("myonclick=window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/po.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=SPRYOMD3290';");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

How would I create this using vb.net